# Update table in chunks

Tags: sql, batch-processing

I am trying to update a large table in chunks and transactions.

This query runs endlessly in case column1 is not updated for some reason. I have another nested query there, which does not necessarily return a value, so some column1's remain as null after the update. This puts my query into an endless loop.

How can I specify a position for "update top" to start with?

Thanks in advance.

---

```
declare @counter int 
declare @total int
declare @batch int

set @total = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table with(nolock))
set @counter = 0 
set @batch = 1000

while (@counter < (@total/@batch) + 1)
begin
BEGIN TRANSACTION

set @counter = @counter + 1 
Update TOP ( @batch ) table

SET column1 = 'something'
where column1 is null 

Commit transaction
end
```

Comment: top n queries without order by clauses don't really make a lot of sense.  The top part has to be based on something.

Comment: Assuming I order by column1. How can capture the next top N during subsequent runs?